# Исходный код стандартных функций php

Tags: php, функции

Как получить исходник php функции `file_get_contents()` или `file_put_contents()` да и любой php функции вообще?

Comment: Вопрос актуален, удалось получить немного, но всё же верю, что можно больше.

Comment: На git·hub нужно идти, cегодня тольно пересматривал функции time() и date(). Очень громоздкой код!

Comment: Мне нужно получить код нестандартной ф-ции

Comment: Ещё предложения будут?

Answer (score 5):

Любая стандартная функция в PHP - обертка над обращением к скомпилинным библиотекам на Си. PHP - оупенсорсный. Можно скачать исходники и достать Си-шную реализацию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как быть если, к примеру, я пользуюсь чужим хостингом, и там есть ф-ция site_getinfo(), как быть в этом случае? Узнать чем дышит эта ф-ция не получится?

Comment: Судя потому, что описания этой функции не на php.net, эта функция не стандартная.

Comment: Ну да, со стандартностью ф-ции я, наверное, ошибся, узнать, как она работает не получится?

Comment: Можно, но только косвенно. Точнее, я не знаю как это сделать напрямую.

А, так, вызываешь phpinfo(), и смотришь какие модули подключены. Стандартные отметаются там этой функции нет.

Comment: Убедился, что это не стандартная функция. Она написана администраторами хостинга. Но мне всё ещё нужно узнать принцип её действия.

Comment: Совсем недавно ковырял исходники ПШП-хотел узнать как работает замена в preg_replace, но ничерта не понял :(  
Исходники здесь:  
https://github.com/php

Comment: Ну еще бы! Парсер регулярок намного более сложный механизм, чем читалка из сокета `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 3):

Как я могу предположить, вы пользуйтесь скриптом на хостинге, в котором есть функция, принцип которой вас интересует. Если у вас нет доступа к данному файлу, то в принципе можете воспользоваться [Класс `ReflectionFunction`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.reflectionfunction.php), который предоставляет функционал для исследования кода

Comment: c момощью стандартной рефлекции можно вытащить содержимое вашей функции, так что вполне полноценное исследование возможно

Comment: Спасибо, похоже это то, что мне нужно. Да, на хостинге есть функция, принцип которой мне не известен, доступа к каким либо файлам тоже нету. Сейчас попробую разобраться с этим классом, если не разберусь - отпишусь. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Попробовал получить данные таким способом:

<?
 echo new ReflectionFunction("site_getinfo");

но кроме списка параметров больше ничего не узнал.

Comment: По ходу разбираюсь, очень полезный класс для реверс-инжиниринга.

Answer (score 2):

Как известно PHP и написан на Сях, идёт на github и видим там [репозиторий](https://github.com/php/php-src). Делаем [поиск по сишному коду в этом репозитории](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aphp%2Fphp-src+file_get_contents&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=C) и находим реализацию функции [`file_get_contents`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5400642e37bee8e0dcbdc898d8dd065f806a8629/ext/standard/file.c#L513).

Точно также можно посмотреть код и других стандартных функций.

Comment: Мне нужна реализации нестандартной php-функции.